# Deleting Empty Cells from Google SpreadSheet Programatically to avoid 5000000 cell limit error

Tags: scala, google-sheets, playframework, google-api

I have written small batch job in Scala language where I first pull the data from database and dump it in google spreadsheet.

Initially the job worked very well but suddenly it started failing with following error :

```
 ERR com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 ERR   "code" : 400,
 ERR   "errors" : [ {
 ERR     "domain" : "global",
 ERR     "reason" : "badRequest"
 ERR {
 ERR   } ],
 ERR   "message" : "This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.",
 ERR    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
 ERR    at
```

Surprisingly, I am inserting a list of 1800 records each having 20 columns. So total number of cells in my case of 36000 but it is far away from the limit 50,00,000 cells mentioned in the error.

I could not find any concrete solution yet but I removed few empty columns from the spreadsheet and the batch job started working properly. So, it might be possible that those empty rows and columns are responsible behind the limit overflow.

I am already doing clean up of entire spreadsheet before inserting the data. But I think, I need to delete the cells which are empty rather than cleaning it up.

Please find following code snippet to check my current implementation. Note that, here, I have used range value "**A2:Z**" as the first row is header and I don't want it to be deleted.

```
def  clearAndInsertRowsToSpreadSheet(itemsToAppend : util.List[util.List[AnyRef]],
                              range : String,
                              spreadSheetId : String){

    clearSpreadSheet(range,spreadSheetId)

    insertRowsToSpreadSheet(itemsToAppend,range,spreadSheetId)

  }

  private def insertRowsToSpreadSheet(itemsToAppend : util.List[util.List[AnyRef]], range : String,
                                      spreadSheetId : String) ={

    val data : ValueRange = new ValueRange()
    data.setValues(itemsToAppend)

    val appendRequest = googleSpreadSheetService.getSheets().spreadsheets()
      .values().append(spreadSheetId, range,data)

    appendRequest.setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
    appendRequest.setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS")

    val appendValuesResponse = appendRequest.execute()

    appendValuesResponse.getUpdates

  }
  private def clearSpreadSheet(range : String, spreadSheetId : String) : String = {

    val clearDataRequest = googleSpreadSheetService.
        getSheets().spreadsheets().
        values().clear(spreadSheetId,range, new ClearValuesRequest())

    val clearResponse = clearDataRequest.execute()

    clearResponse.getClearedRange
  }
```

But, How I can write a code to delete all rows and columns which are empty before dumping my data. I tried with `BatchClearValuesByDataFilterRequest` but it did not work. I am searching for a some mechanism where I can provide a condition to check ROWs and Columns having empty cells.

Any suggestion appreciated !

Comment: If your sheet has many empty cells, it means that at some point you filled with data that had empty cells. So rather than deleting those cells posteriorly, maybe you can sanitize the data and remove empty cells before inserting it into the sheet?

Comment: I have already implemented validations on data. So I can never be empty. I am not sure, how columns with empty cells were added. I can not check those details due to limited access to the spreadsheet. But I want to add a check in my code to remove any such empty rows and columns before insertion to avoid any such error in future.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant remove empty database entries before inserting them into the sheet.

Comment: Here problem is not with data,  there are no empty DB entries present. Problem is with empty cells already present on stylesheet which needs to be deleted before inserting new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Root Cause Of the Problem**

After few more round of testing and observation, I found that the problem was with the way I have used "**append**" function. In my code, I was first performing clean up of spreadsheet and then appending the new data using Append method.

Here, two points needs to be noted.

1. Clear function only clears the cells value but does not delete the cells or release the memory. So those cleared cells remains already occupied.
2. Google API append function actually prepends new data with existing rows(cells) rather than using existing empty cells.

To make it more clear, assume that we have 100 rows with 12 columns. So total 1200 cells are occupied. While executing the code mentioned in problem statement, the clean up function will clean up those 1200 cells but does not delete it. So, Google API considers those cells are as still occupied. Now, while calling append function with a list of 50 objects, the append method will prepend 50 new rows by moving existing 100 rows to downside. So now, after executing my code, total occupied cells will be 1800.

```
Total Number of Old cells = 100 ROWs * 12 Columns  = 1200
Total Number of New cells = 50 ROWs * 12 Columns   = 600
---------------------------------------------------------
Total Number of cell after job execution = 1800
```

So, considering above example, frequent execution of above code will lead our spreadsheet to reach its max allowed cell limit 50,00,000 error.

- **Solutions :**

We can solve above problem by two ways.

1. Remove the unused cells rather than clearing them using **BatchUpdate** and **DeleteDimensionRequest**.
2. Use **Update** method instead of **Append** which will use existing cells to insert the data. But note that you need to clear the spreadsheet before using Update method.

I would suggest to go with solution#2 update method as UpdateResponse provides better in depth statics. It provides total numbers of rows, columns and cells updated which can be used to tracking purpose.

Below is the code snippet for above two solutions :

- **Solution#1.** Remove rows using **BatchUpdate** method and
  **DeleteDimentionRequest** :

**Here, we need to note one point. We can not delete all rows of spreadsheet. So we need to keep on static header in the spreadsheet. And while using DeleteDimentionRequest, the stat index starts with zero.**

```
val dimensionRange : DimensionRange = new DimensionRange()
 dimensionRange.setDimension("ROWS")
 dimensionRange.setStartIndex(1)
 //dimensionRange.setEndIndex(1001)

 val deleteDimensionRequest : DeleteDimensionRequest = new DeleteDimensionRequest()
 deleteDimensionRequest.setRange(dimensionRange)

 val request : Request = new Request()
 request.setDeleteDimension(deleteDimensionRequest)

 val requests : util.List[Request] = new util.ArrayList[Request]()
 requests.add(request)

 val batchUpdateRequest : BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest =new  BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
 batchUpdateRequest.setRequests(requests)

 val batchUpdate: Sheets#Spreadsheets#BatchUpdate =  googleSpreadSheetService.getSheets()
    .spreadsheets()
    .batchUpdate(spreadSheetId, batchUpdateRequest)

 val batchUpdateResponse = batchUpdate.execute()
```

- **Solution#2.** Clean up the cells and call **update** method to insert the
  data :

  //Code

  ```
  private def clearAndInsertRowsToSpreadSheet(itemsToAppend : util.List[util.List[AnyRef]], range : String, spreadSheetId : String) :  UpdateValuesResponse = {

          clearSpreadSheet(range, spreadSheetId)
          updateSpreadSheetData(itemsToAppend,range, spreadSheetId)

        }

        private def updateSpreadSheetData(itemsToAppend : util.List[util.List[AnyRef]], range : String, spreadSheetId : String) ={

          val data : ValueRange = new ValueRange()
          data.setValues(itemsToAppend)

          val updateRequest: Sheets#Spreadsheets#Values#Update = googleSpreadSheetService.getSheets()
            .spreadsheets()
            .values()
            .update(spreadSheetId, range, data)

          updateRequest.setValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED")
          val updateValuesResponse: UpdateValuesResponse = updateRequest.execute()
          updateValuesResponse
        }
        private def clearSpreadSheet(range : String, spreadSheetId : String) : String = {

          val clearDataRequest = googleSpreadSheetService.
            getSheets().spreadsheets().
            values().clear(spreadSheetId,range, new ClearValuesRequest())

          val clearResponse = clearDataRequest.execute()

          clearResponse.getClearedRange
        }
  ```

Hope, above answer is sufficient enough to understand the nature of the problem and its possible solutions.